# PHP mobile redirect Endless loop

Tags: plugins, redirect, mobile, wp-load.php

I have a mobile version I'm building outside of Wordpress in a subfolder on the same server as my Wordpress install. I'm including the wp-load.php file to pull content from the WordPress database.

If I turn this plugin on (http://wordpress.org/plugins/php-mobile-redirect/), it goes into an endless loop.

I realize now by doing this I'm also calling all active plugins. Or at least I think I'm calling the redirect script which is causing the endless loop.

If I go to the normal site, http://s168249.gridserver.com/ on a mobile phone or by spoofing the browser, endless loop.

If I go to the mobile site, http://s168249.gridserver.com/mobile/index.php, on a phone, endless loop.

If I turn off the redirect, I can go to the mobile site without a hitch.

CURRENTLY ALL REDIRECTION IS OFF

So I assume that the include of the mobile redirect script us wp_load.php in the mobile index.php file is what's causing the issue.

Is there a way to exclude just this plugin?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-mobile-redirect/

Comment: How can you "exclude" the plugin and still have it work? Try to clarify this question please.

Comment: [That plugin appears to depend on cookies](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/php-mobile-redirect/trunk/includes/functions.php) Is it possible that that is part of the issue?

Comment: I'm trying to exclude it from the mobile version of the site, not the full site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the plugin at all and in your `function.php` add

```
add_action('init', 'my_mobile_redirect');

function get_first_url_subdir() {
  return str_replace( str_replace( array('http://', 'https://'), '', get_site_url() ), '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
} 

function redirect_mobile_with_cookie() {
  $cookiename = 'redirect_mobile_is_a_mobile_device';
  if ( isset($_COOKIE[$cookiename]) && ($_COOKIE[$cookiename] == 'yes') && strpos(get_first_url_subdir(), '/mobile') !== 0)
    return true;
  return false;
} 

function my_mobile_redirect(){
  if ( redirect_mobile_with_cookie() ) {
     wp_redirect( get_site_url() . '/mobile/');
     exit();
  } elseif  ( strpos(get_first_url_subdir(), '/mobile') !== 0 && wp_is_mobile() ) {
    $cookiename = 'redirect_mobile_is_a_mobile_device';
    setcookie($cookiename, 'yes');
    wp_redirect( get_site_url() . '/mobile/');
    exit();
  }
}
```

Previous functions works with Wordpress `wp_is_mobile` function that do not differentiate between tablets and phones.

If you need to differentiate between tablets and phones you can use the script [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/). Download it, put in a folder. For semplicity here I assume `Mobile_Detect.php` resides in theme root.

The following function works **in combination** with the three above.

```
function my_adv_mobile_redirect() {
   if ( redirect_mobile_with_cookie() ) {
     wp_redirect( get_site_url() . '/mobile/');
     exit();
  } else {
    @include_once( trailingslashit(TEMPLATEPATH) . 'Mobile_Detect.php' );
    if ( ! class_exists('Mobile_Detect') ) return my_mobile_redirect();
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
    // redirects only phones
    if  (strpos(get_first_url_subdir(), '/mobile') !== 0 && ($detect->isMobile() && ! $detect->isTablet())) {
      $cookiename = 'redirect_mobile_is_a_mobile_device';
      setcookie($cookiename, 'yes');
      wp_redirect( get_site_url() . '/mobile/');
      exit();
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to use this advanced function just replace the init action in the previous code with: `add_action('init', 'my_adv_mobile_redirect')`

Comment: This block of code works. I've added an extra else if to bounce you back to regular site if you're trying to access the mobile site. Now I just need to figure out how to exclude all tablet devices and how to make a view full site option with cookies.

Comment: @DaveRottino, see my new code...

Comment: Junk! Now I'm getting the following error:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 103809024 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261900 bytes) in /nfs/c03/h04/mnt/168249/domains/owensgroup.com/html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 940

I can't get it to go at all now.

Comment: @DaveRottino The error was generated by the `get_option` call. I've totally removed that function that is not necessary and, by calling db, slows down the redirect. I've tested in a desktop and it works, it should on a mobile device, too. Probably is a good idea change the cookie name in the code and make it more _customized_ for your site.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but in the `index.php` for your mobile site can you add

`remove_action('init', 'pmr_mobile_redirect');`

this in theory will disable the redirect plugin.

Comment: I tried this and no go. It does remove the redirect. I determined it's working with a little execute code detection BUT on mobile, it still causes a infinite loop.